# get numbers from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

I have a string that can look like this:

```
8=0,2=1,5=1,6=0,7=0
```

I want to extract only the numbers which are followed by `=0`, in this case: 8, 6 and 7

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
'8=0,2=1,5=1,6=0,7=0'
   .match(/\d?=(0{1})/g)
   .join(',')
   .replace(/=0/g,'')
   .split(','); //=> [8,6,7] (strings)
```

or, if you can use advanced [`Array` iteration methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2):

```
'8=0,2=1,5=1,6=0,7=0'.split(',')
     .filter( function(a){ return /=0/.test(a); } )
     .map( function(a){ return +(a.split('=')[0]); } ) //=> [8,6,7] (numbers)
```

Comment: He only wants numbers not `=0` part :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var nums = [];
'8=0,2=1,5=1,6=0,7=0'.replace(/(\d+)=0,?/g, function (m, n) {
    nums.push(+n);
});
```

Note that this returns an array of numbers, not strings.

Alternatively, here is a more concise, but slower, answer:

```
'8=0,2=1,5=1,6=0,7=0'.match(/\d+(?==0)/g);
```

And the same answer, but which returns numbers instead of strings:

```
'8=0,2=1,5=1,6=0,7=0'.match(/\d+(?==0)/g).map(parseFloat);
```

Comment: +1 but you could simplify your regex like this `/(\d+)=0/g` and then remove the `if (keep === '0')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function parse(s)
{
  var a = s.split(",");
  var b = [];
  var j = 0;
  for(i in a)
  {
     if(a[i].indexOf("=0")==-1) continue;
     b[j++] = parseFloat(a[i].replace("=0",""));        
  }
  return b;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Because it's enough to return the numbers. `document.write` will kill the site... . If you delete it, I will upvote your answer.

Comment: @vngeek.exe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice